# Updating JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes which I use to paint a JFrame (see below).

I am trying to refresh the content so it gives the impression of the points randomly "moving". (Ie: Repainting fast enough)

Ideally, I would then like to pass in some parameters to specify at which coordinates the points should appear. However, all I get is a static image.

Any advice?

```
package uk.me.dariosdesk.dirtydemo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            Dimension size = getSize();
            Insets insets = getInsets();

            int w = size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
            int h = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

            Random r = new Random();
            int x = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % w;
            int y = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % h;
            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
        g2d.fillRect(200, 250, 200, 250);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}
```

And

```
package uk.me.dariosdesk.dirtydemo;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PointsExample extends JFrame {
    public PointsExample() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        DrawPanel dpnl = new DrawPanel();
        add(dpnl);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setTitle("Points");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PointsExample ex = new PointsExample();
                ex.setVisible(true);
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ex.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run this in an IDE debugger and stepped through the code to see what is happening?  That is the place to start.  Questions of the type "here's all my code, tell me what's wrong" are generally off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Replace the `PointsExample`'s for-loop with a Swing `Timer`, because I think `Thread.sleep()` is blocking your whole application. I would actually also place the timer inside the `DrawPanel` class and do all the calculations for the next points there, because otherwise the points will also move if you for example resize the frame (i.e. everytime the frame repaints).

Comment: You are calling `getSize()`, `getInsets()` and `new Random()` 1000 times. Why?

Comment: What parameters do you want to pass, to what and from where? How do you want them to affect what is being drawn?

Answer (score 3):

*"all I get is a static image"* is very light on details. But I think LuxxMiner is right, `Thread.Sleep` on your [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is a bad idea. What's more, the Runnable never exits for 1000 seconds. So you are blocking the EDT for 1000 seconds.

What repaint [`Component.repaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) does (emphasis mine):

> If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method **as soon as possible**. Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method **as soon as possible**.

This already signals that this method posts a message to the dispatch thread, which you are blocking with `Thread.Sleep`. What you can do instead is use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to ask for a repaint every second:

> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread.